# Tx Pending. CPFP, BumpFee or do nothing?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-cli, child-pays-for-parent

I have a stuck/pending tx - 14 hours. Its marked as RBF. I'm a bit below the median tx fee. (currently 67 sat/vB vs ~96 sat/vB). BitcoinFees seems to indicate I should get confirmed within 24 hours. I'm not in a rush. The wallet I've sent it from is now empty.

I'm using an old ver of bitcoin-qt (0.17) - for various reasons. The BumpFee command specifies "totalFee" as a param (now deprecated) and the instructions indicate is it is specified in sats. Yet with that ver of the client, fees were specified in btc/kb. I'm **very** nervous about passing a figure like 40000 as the totalFee param value in case I've misunderstood something and it messes with the tx! (As part of the discussion wrt its deprecation, having multiple units was raised as an issue which may cause confusion!)

I also have a bit of btc on binance which I am looking to move to the same destination address - which is mine also.

I'm wondering what my best course of action is.

- wait for 24 hours?
- is it possible to create a parent/child relation from binance as part of transfer the btc? I can't see anything obvious in the withdraw facility ... but I could be missing something.
- is BumpFees a better option? If so perhaps someone could confirm the syntax or reassure me that a totalFee value of ~40000 is safe.
- something else?

thx in advance

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/bumpfee.html) for `bumpfee` says *"fee_rate": amount,        (numeric or string, optional, default=not set, fall back to wallet fee estimation)
                             Specify a fee rate in sat/vB instead of relying on the built-in fee estimator.
                             Must be at least 1.000 sat/vB higher than the current transaction fee rate.
                             **WARNING: before version 0.21, fee_rate was in BTC/kvB**. As of 0.21, fee_rate is in sat/vB."* So I'd assume BTC/kvB for your version 0.17

Comment: Thx vm. Looking at this https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/bumpfee/ it says it is totalFee in sats. I'm concerned if I enter say 40000 and it is fee Rate as you are suggesting the value of the tx will go to the miner. If OTOH it is total fee and I specify it as a fee rate unit, it'll actually reduce the fee. Any thoughts?